# conditionally create user in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I would like to create a user 'foo' in database 'mydb' if the user doesn't already exist. Currently my script looks like this:

```
USE [mydb]
CREATE USER [foo] FOR LOGIN [foo]
GO
```

However if the user already exists, this fails with an error message:

```
Msg 15023, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
User, group, or role 'jsrvpp' already exists in the current database.
```

How can I change the script so that the user is only created if they doesn't already exist?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if a SQL Server login already exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379437/checking-if-a-sql-server-login-already-exists)

Answer (score 58):

You can consult the two system catalogs [sys.server_principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-server-principals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to check for server logins, or [sys.database_principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-principals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in your specific database for users of your database:

```
use myDB
GO

if not exists(select * from sys.database_principals where name = 'foo')
  -- create your database user
   

if not exists(select * from sys.server_principals where name = 'foo')
   -- you need to create a server login first
```

Marc

Comment: I would expect the name of the DB (mydb) to appear in there somewhere, am I missing something?

Comment: you have to be on your db, of course, e.g. "use mydb" before the check

Answer (score 28):

Essentially combining [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778518/conditionally-create-user-in-sql-server/778542#778542) and [marc_s's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778518/conditionally-create-user-in-sql-server/778561#778561), as requested by a comment from Chris.

Books Online says of [sp_grantdbaccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178013.aspx):

> This feature will be removed in a
>   future version of Microsoft SQL
>   Server. Avoid using this feature in
>   new development work, and plan to
>   modify applications that currently use
>   this feature. Use CREATE USER instead.

So to only create a user if the user doesn't already exist, I'd do something like this:

```
/* Make sure User is created in the appropriate database. */
USE mydb
GO

/* Users are typically mapped to logins, as OP's question implies, 
so make sure an appropriate login exists. */
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT principal_id FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = 'foo') BEGIN
    /* Syntax for SQL server login.  See BOL for domain logins, etc. */
    CREATE LOGIN foo 
    WITH PASSWORD = 'sufficiently complex password'
END

/* Create the user for the specified login. */
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT principal_id FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'foo') BEGIN
    CREATE USER foo FOR LOGIN foo
END
```

Despite being deprecated, sp_grantdbaccess does have the advantage of being able to use a parameter or local variable for the user/login name, as in David's answer.  The first alternative I could think of to get something similar to work with CREATE USER was to use dynamic SQL.  For example:

```
/* Make sure User is created in the appropriate database. */
USE mydb
GO

DECLARE @NewUserName sysname;
DECLARE @NewUsersLogin sysname;

SET @NewUserName = 'foo';
SET @NewUsersLogin = 'bar';

/* Users are typically mapped to logins, as OP's question implies, 
so make sure an appropriate login exists. */
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT principal_id FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = @NewUsersLogin) BEGIN
    /* Syntax for SQL server login.  See BOL for domain logins, etc. */
    DECLARE @LoginSQL as varchar(500);
    SET @LoginSQL = 'CREATE LOGIN '+ @NewUsersLogin + 
        ' WITH PASSWORD = ''sufficiently complex password''';
    EXEC (@LoginSQL);
END

/* Create the user for the specified login. */
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT principal_id FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = @NewUserName) BEGIN
    DECLARE @UserSQL as varchar(500);
    SET @UserSQL = 'CREATE USER ' + @NewUserName + ' FOR LOGIN ' + @NewUsersLogin;
    EXEC (@UserSQL);
END
```

Interestingly enough, Books Online also says that `sp_grantdbaccess` actually calls `CREATE USER`, and I noticed in my testing that if you don't explicitly assign a schema, `sp_grantdbaccess` will create one named after the user, while `CREATE USER` will use 'dbo' by default.

Answer (score 16):

This is what we do...

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DBO.SYSUSERS WHERE NAME = @usrName )
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Granting access to the current database to login ' + @usrName + '...'
  -- Grant access to our database
  EXEC SP_GRANTDBACCESS @usrName
END ELSE BEGIN  
  PRINT 'Login ' + @usrName + ' already granted access to current database.'  
END
```

Comment: for new development on SQL Server 2005 I'd use sys.database_principals instead of sysusers and stick with CREATE USER instead of sp_grantdbaccess.

Comment: A bit old, but it should be `sys.server_principals` and not `sys.database_principals` for this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
USE [*Database_Name*];
GO

DECLARE @isUserExist int, @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
SELECT @isUserExist = COUNT(*) from sys.sysusers where name = *User_Name* 
--Checking for User Existence 
IF(@isUserExist = 0) 
BEGIN 
    SET @SQL = 'CREATE USER ' + QUOTENAME(*User_Name*) + ' FOR LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(*User_Name*); 
    EXECUTE(@SQL); 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked exactly the same question regarding the SQL user already existing when the script runs - the question, and some very useful answers are here:

[Checking if a SQL Server login already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379437/checking-if-a-sql-server-user-already-exists)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

```
USE MyDB
GO

BEGIN TRY
  CREATE USER [foo] FOR LOGIN [foo]
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 -- User exists - do nothing
END CATCH
```

Comment: As long as the only potential error is that the user already can login.

Comment: Downvoted because if any other error is raised, like "Password Policy" or "Invalid Login", these errors will be swallowed by the Try/Catch