# How to check if an Azure Sql Server server principal (Login) already exists

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I'm using ARM templates to instantiate a new Sql Server resource on Azure and, as part of the setup, I need to create a few user logins.

It seems that ARM templates do not offer the options to create new user principals therefore I'm considering running a SQL command to do so:

CREATE LOGIN 
    WITH PASSWORD = ''

The problem with using this command is that it fails if the user already exists and therefore it is not idempotent, which is something that we need.

How do I check if a login already exists on an Azure SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following script will create the login on the master database at the logical Azure SQL server level.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = 'simonel')
    CREATE LOGIN simonel WITH PASSWORD = 'BS#ah12!!@#' 
ELSE
    PRINT 'Already exist'
```

The following acript will create the user at the database level, if it does not exist already.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sysusers WHERE name='simonel')
    CREATE USER simonel FOR LOGIN Blah WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo
ELSE
    PRINT 'Already exists'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query:

```
If not Exists (select loginname from master.dbo.syslogins 
    where name = @loginName and dbname = 'PUBS')
Begin
    Select @SqlStatement = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@loginName) + ' 
    FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[PUBS], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]')

    EXEC sp_executesql @SqlStatement
End
```

For more details, you can reference this blog: [Checking if a SQL Server login already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379437/checking-if-a-sql-server-login-already-exists)

Hope this helps.